# Insights into Derived Functor Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm a novice learning algebraic geometry. Although schemes are quite abstract, it's easy to see their relationship with algebraic varieties. However, when reading through derived functor cohomology, if not for Leray's theorem, it would seem miraculous that the derived functor approach indeed yields cohomology. May I ask whether there are insights that allow one to see through the abstract algebra?

Comment: What *is* your definition of cohomology then? The Cech cohomology?

Comment: If you learn some homological algebra for its own sake, this will feel less mysterious